# What does 'each cookie Emilia took to work' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, relative-clauses

The following is one of question sentences from [this exercise on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/xa88397b6:display-quantitative/xa88397b6:mean-median-data-displays/e/mean-median-displays).

> The dot plot below shows how many chocolate chips were in **each cookie Emilia took to work.**

What does 'each cookie Emilia took to work' mean here?
I could come up with two possible meanings.

1. each cookie Emilia eat on her way to work.
2. each cookie Emilia eat in order to get energy so that she can work.

Or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither seems likely.

The word "take" does not mean "eat". It means "carry to a place".

"to work" isn't an infinitive, "to" is a preposition and "work" means "workplace".

These are cookies that Emilia brings to her workplace to share with her colleagues.  It is quite common to bring cookies or other baked goods to your office to share.

That is irrelevant to the mathematical content of the question.  You can ignore the part "Emilia took to work" and the mathematical question remains the same.